# How do I tell Rails to use a custom session ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am trying to maintain a session inside a Rails app which is loaded into an iframe. Because some browsers block third party cookies just setting the session inside the frame doesn't work.

My solution is to create a unique identifier using JS on the parent page and pass it into the iframe. Is there a way to setup the Rails' session management to use this custom session ID rather then the one it generates itself?